# PHP - Storing multiple attributes the most efficient way

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction of storing multiple attributes and their values in SQL?

Say I've got like First Name, Last Name, Company, Twitter, Facebook etc etc. with more attributes that could be added in the future.

There's a couple of methods that have crossed my mind, one is to store all answers in one column, all answers in another by imploding and storing them as like Firstname|||Surname|||Company etc...
Or, I haven't got much experience with them but bitwise operators?

Just looking for the best/most efficient solution really if anyone could give me an idea and maybe an example that'd be great.

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: Let me catch it right: you have a table with some columns and you will need to add / remove some of them later without changing the tabel's structure?

Comment: Is NoSQL an option, or are you locked into using a relational database?

Comment: Locked into relational really. I've no experience with NoSQL so I think it'd take too long to get myself up to scratch with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you are looking for is a way of having variable attributes attached to a given user and you don't want to modify the table everytime there is a new type of attribute. Maybe EAV will help you. It's a tiny bit complex for reporting if your not used to it. But it gives you a very flexible structure. Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)

Tiny example:

```
    Users
    user_id username  paswword email
    1       "katsuke" "abc"    "demo@demo.com"

    User_EAV
    user_id attribute_name value
    1       "First Name"   "Katsuke"
    1       "Last Name"    "Isikashi"
    1       "Library Card" "14124214"
    1       "Dental Card"  "asd123123"
```

Hope that helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Ah, yeah I think after looking further into it this is going to be the best way of storing the data. Thanks for your input, appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to store and retrieve them (that is not bulk update, sort or search by them) you can go with the base structure in a normal table and the extended values in an serialized array (or json). Doctrine has support for this (`column: {additionalattrs: {type: object}}`)

Actually, if you want to search, json and serialize are still quite searchable in plaintext, but don't count on any indexing, and be ready for some false-positives.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs you can add a 1:N attribute table

```
id:     integer
name:   string
value:  string
```

You can also consider just adding non required fields as an attribute and add required fields in your main table. This will allow you to add more fields later on.